# Read csv and only append new rows

Tags: php, csv

I am loading a csv file into my script then I go through it, filter it, and send relevant parts to a database. The thing is I read this file every 15 minutes and the files can get big sometimes. I need to start at a certain line to accomplish this.

THis is my code, http://codepad.org/1rFnrJnL
I use codepad because it is pretty hefty.

At line 65 I run the function loadCSV. 
$dbcnt is the number of rows in the database at this time and $l is the counter that increase for each row.

At line 81 I check if $l is bigger or equal to $dbcnt which would mean that there are new rows and lets push them to the array.

**The issue is that** it writes data in this order (date) 2014/03/05 2014/03/06 2014/03/07 then starts at maybe 06 and 07 after that again so it repeats.

My code is most likely faulty, how would you do this?

Comment: Can you add DDL(Schema) of `tbl_data`; i.e. output of `show create table tbl_data`. Am I right in saying duplicates is the problem now?

Comment: Yes, duplicates is the issue. There is nothing wrong with the table_data I've tested it throughly.

Comment: Ok, When do you say a record is duplicate? Are we to assume CSV file is being appended not overwritten. Also add Code over here for future reference.

Comment: I use robocopy to move the csv file to one site to another every 15 minute, then I read it. Each time I run the script it duplicated all everything.